# How can I retrieve [TARGETDIR] or [USER INPUT DIR when install time] after install MSI packages?

Tags: c++, windows-installer

I am searching now how get targetdir msi packages that already installed (products).

Sometimes User input target dir when install time. I want this dir-path.

But I can not find target dir in registry.

I tried like these.

**MsiOpenPackage** ... C:\Windows\Installer\*.msi

**MsiGetTargetPath** ... (h, _T("TARGETDIR"), T, &S);

all enum component and  **MsiGetComponentPath** return specific files. But I cannot select which one is TARGET-DIR path.

All...  not worked.

I wanna help.

Answer (score 0):

The MSI must have set the ARPINSTALLLOCATION property to the main application directory like TARGETDIR during the install (obviously after it's been chosen). This is what makes the APIs work, specifically MsiGetProductInfo ({ProductCode}, ...INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLLOCATION ...)

Not all setups bother to do this.

This ends up as InstallLocation in the Uninstall registry entry.

Comment: thanks, but basically i collected INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLLOCATION. Some softwares do not write that information. so I can not find..T.T

Comment: Well that's what I said, right, and if they don't do it then they don't do it. So the short answer is that you can't get them for all software, so you're out of luck if they don't. That's ok because you don't know that there even IS a targetdir. A product that installs to the GAC and common files won't have anything in any "targetdir". What's the problem you're trying to solve, and why does finding targetdirs help, given that not all setups record it or don't have a main app dir.